# CMake and catkin search the wrong "include" folder name

Tags: c++, cmake, ros, catkin

I'm relatively new to CMake and ROS world.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and ROS1 Noetic. I was learning to use Git and the version confliction happened. I've decided to use `-f` to force pull and push.(It work thought)

However, when I back to my ROS workspace and compile files, CMake shows

```
CMake Error in hector_slam/src/hector_slam/hector_mapping/CMakeLists.txt:
  Imported target "Boost::thread" includes non-existent path

    "/include"
```

So I remove the hector_slam dir for testing, and this time the catkin shows following warning

```
catkin_package() absolute include dir '/include' does not exist
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/noetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:102 (_catkin_package)
  pepperl_fuchs-master/pepperl_fuchs_r2000/CMakeLists.txt:24 (catkin_package)
```

It seems like both CMake and catkin_make are search for folder with name "/include", instead of "include".

I've also tried to remove the `devel` and `build` folder then compile again, but the `catkin_make` doesn't work, does anyone has similar experience on it?

Comment: Do you have any other projects in that workspace?